# how to remove :hover from element when suddenly browser window lost focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magic-methods

For example: open [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/932Km/) and place your windows like this: [image: this]:
Then place cursor over the jsfiddle red region to make it `:hover` (green) and now move cursor to the other window. Region still green! How to avoid of it?

Comment: what is that an 'always on top' window? how do you put that window on top of browser and still able to focus in the browser window?

Comment: also, what is your use-case? this seems extremely esoteric

Comment: This is a Chrome specific issue. It doesn't detect the mouse leaving the browser if it moves into a window that sits on top of it. chrome only fires the 'window exit' event when you click into something outside of the browsers viewport. If you place something over the viewport and do..well..exactly what you're trying to do, then you get this issue.

Comment: Looks like it is an OS/Browser combination bug. You are not going to get a fix from people here. File a bug with the vendor[s].

Comment: So, thanks a lot, everybody, seems that there is no helpful decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to click on the new window in order for the hover element to lose focus.  The jsFiddle window still has focus, even when you hover over a different window.  Window focus won't change until you click on the new window.

Comment: i think part of his problem is that he is using linux with some really weird window focus settings

Comment: @mkoryak No, it's not. I tested on Mountain Lion, IE7 and Ubuntu. Same issue, all 3 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can explicitly remove the :hover.  What you could do is change your css to require some outer container having a class and then remove that when the window loses focus:

JS

```
$(window).focus(function () {
    $("#outer").addClass('focusedContainer');
});
$(window).blur(function () {
    $("#outer").removeClass('focusedContainer'); 
});​
```

CSS

```
.button{
    background: red;
}
.focusedContainer>.button:hover{
    background: green;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/932Km/11/
    ​

Comment: This does not work in Chrome. Which is the browser he's having difficulties with.

Comment: You are right it doesn't 100% correct the issue. It does fix the issue if the user then clicks on the topmost window, which will fire the blur event, which is a little better than nothing at all.

Comment: What? if I drag...say, 'My computer' over the Chrome Window, Fire the Hover event and drag directly into 'My Computer' I can click, launch applications, etc, and it will never fire his event. Your method doesn't work around anything and simply over complicates a normalized hover process.